# R-mode is named r-mode and causing issues

Tags: emacs, knitr, ess

I'm trying to get [polymode](https://github.com/vspinu/polymode) to work with .Rnw files, but it assumes that R-mode is named `R-mode` and on my system, ESS installed it as `r-mode`. How can I tell it that this is the same thing? I have this in my .emacs file:

```
;;; R modes
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.Rnw" . poly-noweb+r-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.Rmd" . poly-markdown+r-mode))
```

Strangely, if I open up a .Rmd file, it recognizes everything properly.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by installing ESS via `sudo apt-get install ess` rather than from MELPA. I don't really understand why this would make a difference, but it fixed the problem for me!